# Moving div along the circular path with fixed angle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know if it is possible to move div along the circular path with fixed angle. E.g. moving div only 45 degrees of circular path and than make it to come back to starting point, like effect similar to pendulum.

Hope, that attached picture will make sense to what I meant.

Many thanks for all help.
Looking forward,

[image]

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far

Comment: Absolute positioning and some simple trig. Very possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your updated requirement (that the object itself should always be vertical while rotating), I have modified my previous code.

There may be another approach but I could think of this only at the moment. Here, I have wrapped our original 'ball' element inside another div. Now, the outer div does the normal pendulum animation. But, in addition, the inner object also does a counter-rotating animation which keeps it vertically straight at all points during the animation.

Please notice that the inner object has its transform-origin as default which is `center center`, because it needs to rotate around its own axis only.

```css
#container
{
  background-color: #777;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
}

#ball
{
  animation: swing 1s ease 0s infinite;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  transform-origin: center 150px;
  width: 50px;
}

@keyframes swing{
  0%{transform: rotate(-22.5deg);}
  50%{transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
  100%{transform: rotate(-22.5deg);}
}

#main-content
{
  animation: innerswing 1s ease 0s infinite;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes innerswing{
  0%{transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
  50%{transform: rotate(-22.5deg);}
  100%{transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="ball">
    <div id="main-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your solution @Mohit, it seems to work in my case. Would you like to elaborate a little bit more on how **X** should be calculated for `{transform: rotate( X deg);}` if I need to move object for 10 degrees in circular path from angle 125 to angle 135?

Comment: @o.O Do you count angles clockwise or counter-clockwise? A quick fix is to just keep the difference between the 2 angles as the rotation amount you want (10deg in your case) and then adjust it by moving the starting angle value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [css animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) alone. First you should shift the [transform origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin?v=example) to a point that will server as the center of the pendulum. Now, you can simply define the angles for rotation as being 45 degree apart. Please check below code as an example:

```css
#container
{
  background-color: #777;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
}

#ball
{
  animation: swing 1s ease 0s infinite;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  transform-origin: center 150px;
  width: 50px;
}

@keyframes swing{
  0%{transform: rotate(-22.5deg);}
  50%{transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
  100%{transform: rotate(-22.5deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your swift reply, very helpful. Is it possible to move object along circular path without rotating it? I have updated question with new picture.